# How to use Stanza.io without browserify?

Tags: javascript, npm, bundle, ionic-framework, browserify

Using **Ionic**, how can I compile/include **stanza.bundle.js** without the need of browserify? Or should I just get used to use browserify?

I'm trying to add the **Stanza.io** library to my **Ionic** app.
I was thinking about including it like that:

```
<script src="stanza.bundle.js"></script>
```

But there are so many JS link in the **stanza.bundle.js** files that I need to copy to my **www** folder, without knowing if it will works. Also, all JS links are absolute paths.

The commands I used to compile **Stanza.io**

```
npm install stanza.io
cd node_modules/stanza.io
npm install
make
```

I'm not very familiar with npm, that's why my question doesn't go very deep.

Comment: i don't know `Ionic` but with browserify it would work like this: `browserify -r stanza.io > stanza.bundle.js`

Comment: Thanks, I still don't know if I want to use browserify with angular though haha

Comment: @halfer Got solution for this?

Comment: @Optimus: no, I just edited the question. I've no experience with these technologies.